# Exploring CSV with Java

Tags: java, database, csv, oop

I have an assignement on Java : to explore a CSV with some APIs
We have several csv file with name/gender/Number of Birth ,first girls and then boys like this :

[image: First girls and then boys]

There is one function given by my teacher :

```
private int getCsvRowOfMostPopularNameByGender(int year, String gender){
    int rank = -1;
    SEFileUtil seFileUtil = new SEFileUtil(getPathToCSV(year));
    for (CSVRecord record : seFileUtil.getCSVParser()) {
        String currGender = record.get(1);
        if (currGender.equals(gender)){
            rank = (int) record.getRecordNumber();
            break;
        }
    }
    return rank;
} // returning index of the First popular Name
```

Now I need to write a function to return the rank of a given name.
I wrote this using the example function :

```
private int getRank (int year, String name, String sex ){

    SEFileUtil seFileUtil = new SEFileUtil(getPathToCSV(year));
    for (CSVRecord record : seFileUtil.getCSVParser()) {
        if (record.get(0).equals(name) && record.get(1).equals(sex)) {
            return (int) record.getRecordNumber() - getCsvRowOfMostPopularNameByGender(year,sex) + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

But then I wanted to find by myself i wanted to access directly at the index i of the Csv file corresponding to the year in question and returning -1 in case of classement out of range.
I tried to declare new object type CSVParser or CSVRecord like we used in the for loop but whithout any success

I think we are using the apach API : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/jacoco/org.apache.commons.csv/index.source.html

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

PS : You should consider splitting your code
1. read data and map to a proper object (1per csv line)
2. Treat your data.

Readability is the key ;)

```
private int getRow(int index) {

        SEFileUtil seFileUtil = new SEFileUtil(getPathToCSV(year));
        Iterable it = seFileUtil.getCSVParser();
        int i = 0 ;
        while ( it.hasNext() && i < index){
            it.next();
            index++;
        }
       if ( it.hasNext()){
           return it.next() ;
       }
       return ??
    }
```